# Android/Kotlin - okhttp4 GET request - return response headers and not follow redirect

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I'm making a GET request in Android Kotlin. The code below is a basic starting point. The response returns a "302 Found" redirect, and the code gets `Location` in the response headers.

I started with `volley` and have switched to https://square.github.io/okhttp/ after investigating the alternatives mentioned in below comments, thanks to R'Js help.

In `build.gradle`:

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
```

The networking part is now working. The async / callback appears necessary, as execution begins in MainActivity (as described in https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#asynchronous-get-kt-java):

I now want to get the header value back to update the `TextView` somehow in the right scope. Perhaps I need to

- create another callback to update this, or
- pass in a handle to the TextView and do the work inside the existing callback
- something else?

```kotlin
package com.example.testlinks

// Example deep linking app

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import okhttp3.*
import java.io.IOException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        handleIntent(intent)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        Log.i("MainActivity", "onNewIntent called")
        handleIntent(intent)
    }

    private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "handleIntent called")

        val appLinkAction = intent.action
        val appLinkData: Uri? = intent.data
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW == appLinkAction) {
            // handle URL
            val res : TextView = findViewById(R.id.result)
            res.text = appLinkData.toString()

            // Show this on our simple example app
            val location = makeRequest(appLinkData)
            val originalUrl : TextView = findViewById(R.id.originalURL)

        }
    }

    // Basic URL GET request.
    // See https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-OkHttp
    //     https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/

    private fun makeRequest(url : Uri?) {
        // More efficient click-tracking with HTTP GET to obtain the "302" response, but not follow the redirect through to the Location.
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .followRedirects(false)
            .build()

        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url.toString())
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val originalURL = response.headers["Location"]
                if (originalURL != null) {
                    println(originalURL) // TODO: pass value back to calling function
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Volley? I'd suggest you go with HttpUrlConnection or even better - Retrofit 2

Comment: Ah. I used it because it was recommended in the official docs here. https://developer.android.com/training/volley. Beyond the basic training materials, Kotlin seems to have poor reference material on libraries (compared to, say, Golang) and poor discoverability of libraries. Will have a poke around Retrofit 2.

Comment: When I first started making android apps, I used HttpUrlConnection which was quite easy to get into hence why I suggest trying it first. Retrofit is quite harder since it uses more advanced things like `Annotations` which, at least from my personal experience were a bit difficult to get a grasp on in the beginning. Try taking a look at retrofit and if you find it hard, just use HttpUrlConnection and you will be fine for some time until you get deeper understanding on Kotlin and Android development.

Comment: hmm Retrofit 2 seems to be for clients with APIs where parsing the returned JSON is the main task. OKHttp (which underlies Retrofit and is also published by square.io) looks to be a better choice here? https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/ again all documentation seems to be "examples" rather than reference material.

Comment: It is indeed better optimized to work with APIs, however, you are able to get a simple string response and from there do whatever you need with it. Use ScalarsConverterFactory with Response<String> as a return parameter. You can also try okhttp, but I have never used it so I can’t really help with that

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Unlike iOS, you can update a `TextView` object directly in the callback thread.

Working code:

```kotlin
package com.example.testlinks

// Example deep linking app

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import okhttp3.*
import java.io.IOException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        handleIntent(intent)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        Log.i("MainActivity", "onNewIntent called")
        handleIntent(intent)
    }

    private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "handleIntent called")

        val appLinkAction = intent.action
        val appLinkData: Uri? = intent.data
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW == appLinkAction) {
            // handle URL
            val res : TextView = findViewById(R.id.result)
            res.text = appLinkData.toString()

            // Show this on our simple example app. The function updates the TextView itself
            makeRequest(appLinkData)
        }
    }

    // Basic URL GET request.
    // See https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-OkHttp
    //     https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/

    private fun makeRequest(url: Uri?) {
        // More efficient click-tracking with HTTP GET to obtain the "302" response, but not follow the redirect through to the Location.
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .followRedirects(false)
            .build()

        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url.toString())
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val locationURL = response.headers["Location"]
                if (locationURL != null) {
                    Log.i("locationURL", locationURL)
                    // Show this on our simple example app
                    val originalUrl : TextView = findViewById(R.id.originalURL)
                    originalUrl.text = locationURL
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

[.gif of app running](https://github.com/SparkPost/deep-links/blob/main/Android/anim.md)